# Mongo -- aggregating the total number of results together with the documents BUT limiting the range?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am running a text-search aggregation on a collection and all is well, however, I only want to display 20 results at a time as text search will have hundreds of matches and in most cases what you're looking for will be among the top 20 results.

I have had success so far using 2 groups and during the first just pushing the $$ROOT for the next group but the issue is then the $limit part doesn't apply anymore as the shape of the result will be 1 document with a property that contains ALL results.

Example:

```
 { $match: { $text: { $search: body.searchTerms } } },
    { $sort: { $score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } },
    { $group: { id_: null, resultsCount: { $sum: 1 }, documents: {  "$push": "$$ROOT"  } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$site.UNID',
        title: { $first: '$title' },
      }
    },
    { $match: { score: { $gt: matchScore } } },
    { $limit: 20 },
    {
      $project: {
        UPRN: '$documents.UPRN',
        title: '$documents.title',
      }
    }
```

The query might not be 100% right as I have lost that initial version -- but the issue is running that $limit operator on what's inside documents and not on the root result.

Comment: please provide some data

Comment: @matthPen data is irelevant --- ANY collection whatsoever with 12 documents, try to aggregate the total number of documents of a query BUT limit the actual documents you send using limit and skip so you can get 10 at a time whilst still having the total number of matches with every query.